# Python regular expression \W: with vs without parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

Below is a quick demo. Using `\W` for matching non-words and split a given string. Why is there a difference between with and without parenthesis?

```
>>> s = "abc:def:ghi"
>>> p = "(\W+)"
>>> q = "\W+"
>>> import re
>>> re.split(p, s, flags=re.UNICODE)
['abc', ':', 'def', ':', 'ghi']
>>> re.split(q, s, flags=re.UNICODE)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: This is explained in the very second sentence of the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). You are expected to at least check the documentation before asking a question here.

Comment: I saw that before asking, but here I am asking exactly what that sentence means.

Comment: The sentence means that your demo works exactly the way you've observed it to work. Why do you find it noteworthy that a function would yield different output when given different input?

Comment: The thing is, it is the "same" input in the sense of matching a regular expression. However, that one was overloaded in this function with more meanings, i.e., to include the matched components into the result. Now I fully understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) documentation:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

For reference, wrapping parts of a regular expression in parentheses creates a `capturing group`. These are groups of the pattern that can later be referenced as individual entities.

Comment: I am just confused by this sentence .. would you mind expand and explain it a bit?

Comment: Da*n! I got it! I was confused because during reasoning I mistakingly regard \W as \w... that's a silly mistake but thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I saw your edit. The concept of capturing group was well understood, but I've got to say that this API seems a bad design.. Using an optional argument to indicate to include the matching component(s) seems more elegant of a software design, than changing regex which is a different concern to be separated. Anyway, good enough answer to accept! Thanks!

Comment: @Bruce: I figured it was understood -- just adding detail for any beginners that might stumble upon this in the future. I agree with your bones about the  API -- it definitely isn't intuitive. I was stumped on this till I took a look at the docs.